# when to use lateinit, init block, and companion object. Kotlin

Tags: constructor, kotlin, init

I am working on the android Bluetooth chat project from the developer site and i am trying to use Kotlin instead of java. i am new to Kotlin and i am just having some confusion about the "right" way to use my init block and lateinit keyword along with my companion objects. in the code that i am posting i do not have a companion object but i am wondering if i should. so far i mainly just use a companion object as a way to sort of imitate java's static class members, or to sometimes contain class constants. as for my init block i am basically using for a constructor. That is other that the assignment of members passed in through the actual constructor defined in the class declaration. As for lateinit, i am using that to declare members that i don't want to immediately initialize but also don't want to make nullable. Please let me know if this is correct usage or thing's for me to change if it is not. Here is my code:

```
    inner class AcceptThread(val secure:Boolean) : Thread(){
    lateinit var mmServerSocket:BluetoothServerSocket
    lateinit var mSocketType:String

    init {
        var tmp:BluetoothServerSocket? = null
        mSocketType = if (secure) "Secure" else "Insecure"

        try {
            if (secure){
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE, UUID_SECURE)
            } else{
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_INSECURE, UUID_INSECURE)
            }
        }catch (ioe:IOException){
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: $mSocketType listen() failed", ioe)
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp!!
        mState = STATE_LISTEN
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `lateinit` here considering you're initialising your variables in the constructor. If you would for example initialise the variables in a lifecycle method like onCreate(), then you could use a `lateinit var`.

Also, I think you could refactor your init block to eliminate the tmp variable:

```
inner class AcceptThread(val secure:Boolean) : Thread() {
val mmServerSocket: BluetoothServerSocket
val mSocketType: String = if (secure) "Secure" else "Insecure"

init {
    try {
        mmServerSocket = if (secure) {
            mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE, UUID_SECURE)
        } else {
            mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_INSECURE, UUID_INSECURE)
        }
    } catch (ioe: IOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: $mSocketType listen() failed", ioe)
    }
    mState = STATE_LISTEN
}
```

Comment: the only problem I am having with this is that I am unable to use Val for mmServerSocket. I am getting a message that property must be initialized or abstract. So don't use lateinit? Just make it a nullable var? What would you suggest?

Comment: So apparently with try-catch blocks you can't use val, which sort of makes sense considering the try-catch implies you're not guaranteed to get a valid value for the variable. So I think the best practice here would be to use a nullable var.

Comment: ok thanks for the help. I have made these changes and all is working well.

Comment: Here, if `try-catch` fails, you end up with a useless object (at least it seems so to me). So don't catch it, or if you do, rethrow the exception.

Answer (score 2):

> Please let me know if this is correct usage or thing's for me to
>   change if it is not.

There are two things that I'll point out regarding your code.

1. You don't need the `lateinit` keyword on both `mmServerSocket` and `mSocketType` because you are initializing both variables in the constructor. You would have needed it, if the variables would have been initialized after the creation.
2. There's one case that can throw an exception. The variable `tmp` can be null if an `IOException` is thrown. In that case, when you assign `tmp` to `mmServerSocket` a `KotlinNullPointerException` will be thrown.
   You have several possibilities to fix it: you can handle a default case in the `catch` block, you can make `mmServerSocket` nullable, etc..